# How to store filename in csh file

Tags: csh

This is my code saved in this file: **runner.csh**
I am trying to get a filename in *file1*. This *file1* contains a list of tests. For this case *file1* is: list_of_tests.list).

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set file1 = $<
echo "This is the file: $file1"
foreach line ("`cat $file1`")
        echo "Test to be run: $line"
```

I want to be able to run in CSHELL my runner.csh as long as with other commands as follows:

```
>setenv $HOME /home/project/user3
>runner.csh list_of_tests.list
>ls $HOME
```

Comment: Are you sure you really want to write a script in csh? (Why?)

Comment: I need to! Tool we are using only accepts csh.